# About the use of curly braces

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, syntax

Although I use LaTeX a lot, I still have a lot to learn about it, and I still have many questions which remain unanswered. One in particular bothers me: when and why must I use curly brackets when giving arguments to  a function like `\cos` or `\sin`?

I tend to use curly brackets everywhere and write `\cos{x}`, because that's how it was written on documents I used to teach myself. However, I see a lot of LaTeX documents where the syntax is simply `\cos x`.

Does it have any importance? Maybe when writing a lot of these functions at a time, like `r\sin \theta d\phi`?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think the braces are extraneous because, from a LaTeX point of view, math operators do not take arguments.  I should temper my statement by saying the braces will insure that the operator sees an adjacent math atom, whereas if the first token following the operator were something other than a math atom, spacing could be different.  For example, `$\cos = 3$` produces different spacing than `$\cos {= 3}$`.  But that is not an issue unless you are using very strange notation.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes or even standard notations the spacing in `$\cos(\phi+\theta)$` is adversely affected if you do `$\cos{(\phi+\theta)}$`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Note that the braces are not just not required, they should not be used as `\cos` does not take an argument the braces form a group and force the term to lose any special math class that it would otherwise have.

`\cos` is a "`\mathop`" operator and `(` is a "`\mathopen`" but a term surrounded by `{`..`}` is always a "`\mathord`". TeX uses different space between a `\mathop` and a `\mathopen` than between a `\mathop` an a `\mathord` (because `log(x)` does not need any space but `log x` does).

Compare

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\cos(\phi+\theta)$

$\cos{(\phi+\theta)}$

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: I'd also add `\cos{\arccos{x}}` that shows the opposite (wrong) spacing.

Comment: I don't understand why `\cos{(\phi+\theta)}` and `\cos{\arccos{x}}` would be considered incorrect. They look fine to me. I understand that, usually, if I have a function called f, then I would want to say `f(x)` and have no space, but I think when the function name is multiple characters and typeset differently, the space actually adds readability.

Comment: @WillR well I think it looks wrong but actually the main point is that the braces are not "superfluous" or "optional"  in the way that `x^2` is the same as `x^{2}` if  you add them they change the output.

Comment: Time to change my habits then! Thank you very much for your answer. :-)

Answer (score 20):

operators like `\cos` or `\sin` don't require curly braces, because they don't
take arguments; they're simply substitutions.

any command that takes an argument is best fed that argument in braces.
even if the argument is a single, unexpandable token (such as the letter "x"),
where braces are optional, it's not improper to provide the braces.  in fact,
it's probably a good idea to get in the habit of using them, since what may
look like a single token (it will always begin with a backslash) may expand
to more than one token and cause problems.

(the final example in the question would be improved by the addition
of a thin space: `r\sin \theta \, d\phi`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I finally get it, I didn't know the difference between substitutions and actual commands that take arguments. I'll look that up!